# Django dumpdata of multi-table inherited objects

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to `./manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary` my classes, which are:

```
class SuperClassManager(Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, identifier):
        return self.get(identifier=identifier)

class SuperClass(Model):
    objects = SuperClassManager()

    identifier = CharField(max_length=31, unique=True)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.identifier, )

class Class(SuperClass):
    pass
```

But the dumped data is:

```
[
{
    "model": "app.superclass",
    "fields": {
        "identifier": "identifier"
    }
},
{
    "model": "app.class",
    "fields": {}
}
]
```

There's no way to relate the `Class` instance to the `SuperClass` instance in this case. What am I missing? Why isn't the `superclass_ptr` existent in `Class` (which points to `SuperClass`) being serialized so it is possible to relate the instances?

Problem being: I have more than one subclass to my superclass and many instances of each subclass. So I need this relation to happen so my fixtures will make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a bug, and the patch is under construction: https://github.com/django/django/pull/7231. So, no answer appropriate for this question, except wait for the patch.